# Move image onScroll from left to right inside of its div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to build a component with a background image which moves when the user scrolls through the page. I have written a useEffect hook to save in state where the user scrolled so far.

```
const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScrollY(window.scrollY);
    };
    handleScroll();

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

This is the css of my div

```
.moving-image {
  min-height: 420px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
    url("../images/door.jpg");
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

How can I apply a animation which changes the position of the image onScroll?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a CSS animation you can define an animation using `keyframes` and load that animation in a class

e.g.

```
@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.useAnimate {
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
}
```

And then apply the class to the element you want to animate on scroll

```
const element = document.querySelector(".moving-image");
const handleScroll = () => {
  element.classList.add("useAnimate");
  setScrollY(window.scrollY);
};
```

---

If you want to animate using JavaScript, then you can use the `style` property of the element.

```
const element = document.querySelector(".moving-image");
const handleScroll = () => {
  element.style.transform = `translateX(${window.scrollY}px)`;
  setScrollY(window.scrollY);
};
```